# wrong foreground color under cursorline

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I recently turned on cursorline in my .vimrc:

```
set cursorline
hi CursorLine ctermbg=54 cterm=NONE
```

However, it doesn't seem to work very well with syntax highlighting. For example,

[image]

As you can see on the cursor line, the color of the string literal is a darker red than it is off the cursor line, which is very difficult on my eyes given my background scheme. (Of course, I could change my background scheme to fix this, but I don't want to do that.) I'd prefer to find away to make the syntax highlighting scheme the same for cursorline as it is off the cursorline, but I can't figure out how. I don't even know *why* it's different, since as far as I know, I don't have any command which explicitly makes the syntax scheme different on the cursorline. How can I fix this?

Comment: It's possible that the other highlight groups are `bold`.

Comment: You can set `ctermfg` to some matching one like `ctermfg=green` or change to some other colorscheme